# What is the concept hidden behind the term "command"?

Tags: command-line, command, terminology

I have been using, studying and developing for Linux for quite a few years now, and over time, I have successfully convinced a few people to *join the cause*, and make the switch to Linux.

However, when these people went discovering this brand new world, every one of them eventually came to me, asking *what the command was to do this or that*:

- What's the command to install a piece of software?
- What's the command to list currently directory contents?
- What's the command to open my web browser?
- ...

To me though, it feels like they are asking the wrong questions. Indeed, I would actually expect them to ask:

- What program do we use to manage software installed on the system?
- What program can list current directory contents?
- What are the available web browsing programs?
- ...

It would seem to me that the term **command** is a very abstract word used to describe pretty much everything you type after your shell prompt. With this thinking, several of the newcomers I brought started to believe that:

- Linux is made of a huge amount of commands.
- There is a command for everything, and every command does one thing specifically.
- By learning more commands, I'll become more capable as a Linux user/administrator.
- By running `./something` I don't run a command, but a program stored in my current directory, probably something I compiled myself.
- ...

Due to that, I tend not to use the word **command**, and prefer to use **program** or **executable file**. I also explain that these executable files can be found automatically, without typing their absolute paths, thanks to the `$PATH` mechanism. Thanks to that, typing `ls` executes `/bin/ls`, which is a **program** stored in `/bin`, a directory registered within the `$PATH` variable.

Still, I come across the word **command** in many books, tutorials, guides, ... which eventually brought this question to my mind: does the word *command* actually have a meaning in the UNIX/Linux vocabulary? Does it refer to an actual concept other than *"whatever you type in your terminal"*?

Comment: there is the *command* `command` which, if nothing else, serves to moved the executed *command* out of *command* position, like `command ls` or `command while`.

Comment: `sudo make me a sandwich`...

Comment: @jasonwryan  Rats: now I have to spend this afternoon writing that Makefile. Although `make` knows some neat recipes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [POSIX shell spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/xcu_chap02.html) refers to *simple commands*, *compound commands*, *command position*, and the *command* `command`.

The first two reference how/when a shell *command* is parsed and executed. For instance:

```
#one compound command
{ simple command; simple command && simple command; }
```

The *compound command* is how much the shell must read in as input before evaluating and executing its constituent *simple commands*.

*command position* is the first word in each *simple command* and it has special significance in that it determines how the rest of the *command* is to be parsed. Certain *reserved words*, *(such as `if` and `while`)*, when in *command position*, can indicate to the parser that what follows should be interpreted as a *compound command* and not merely a *simple command*.

The *command* `command` can serve to move a *command* out of *command position*. For instance, these two would be executed identically, but potentially parsed differently:

```
command simple command
simple command
```

Answer (score 0):

A *command line* is the entire line that you type into the shell, which tells the system to perform some action. The *command* is generally the first word of the command line. It usually identifies a program to run, but it can also be a keyword that's used for control flow (e.g. `if` or `while`) or a built-in command for shell-specific operations (e.g. `read`, `set` or `export`). Sometimes *command* is used to refer to the whole command line; the context makes it clear which is meant.

A common distinction these days is between commands and applications. In a GUI environment, an application is a program started using the graphical shell -- commands are invoked by typing in the shell.

The answers to the example questions you gave would be:

- What's the command to install a piece of software? Something like `apt-get install`.
- What's the command to list current directory contents? `ls`
- What's the command to open my web browser? `firefox &` or `chrome &`, most likely. Although if you're using a window system, there's probably a menu from which you'd select thr browser, so you wouldn't use a command to do this.